# c++ Adding multiple variables on what user inputs

Tags: c++

I don't know how to ask about this since im new at c++ and im not good at English sorry for that.

So Id made a restaurant menu in c++ where there's a list of items in the menu , but the problem is I can only choose 1 item and sum it up, How can I make choose multiple items in the menu like for example

Menu list

1. food 1
2. food 2
3. food 3

Choose an item above : 1 3
then show what are the list of what user inputs and sum it up and its prices.

I was thinking about using while loop, that while user input char 'c' means checkout it will sum it up everything

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to use a flag variable to determine if the user is done adding stuff to the cart.

For example, the interface looks like this

```
Menu list
-
food 1
food 2
food 3
-
quit (q)
```

Then its just a matter of seeing if the `input == "q"` and breaking out of the loop if it is

```
while(true){ 
    cin << input;
    if(input == "q") break;
    else //other-logic-here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Way to implement your idea:

```
const int menu[]{ 10,20,30 };
int a=0, b=0, c=0;

cout << "enter your mix.(a=10,b=20 and c=30). Press other keys to sum." << endl;
char input;
cin >> input;

while (input != 'q')
{
    switch (input)
    {
        case 'a'  :a += menu[0]; break;
        case 'b'  :b += menu[1]; break;
        case 'c'  :c += menu[2]; break;
        default:
            cout << a << " + " << b << " + " << c <<" = "<<  a + b + c << endl;
            a = b = c = 0;
            cout << "enter a,b,or c." << endl;
    }
    cin >> input;
}
```

Results:

```
 enter your mix.(a=10,b=20 and c=30). Press other keys to sum.
b
b
c
c
c
7
0 + 40 + 90 = 130
enter a,b,or c.
```